# How to map java.time.Year and others java.time types using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8, java-time

There's `hibernate-java8` JAR providing adapters for a couple of classes like `Instant`, `LocalDate`, etc., but some classes from `java.time`, e.g., `Year`, `Month`, `YearMonth` are missing. These classes get stored like an unknown `Serializable`, which is needlessly wasteful.

Surely I could use an `int year` instead of `Year year`, but I don't think, it's a good idea.

It looks like writing the `YearJavaDescriptor` should be pretty easy, however, I wonder why it's missing. Especially in case of `YearMonth`, I'd strongly prefer an existing adapter, ist there any? *Or am I doing something stupid?*

I'm unsure as googling returns nothing.

Comment: I think this answers your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40825495/java-time-yearmonth-as-a-type-within-entity

Comment: One piece of advice when serialising / encoding a type like `YearMonth`. [Think of your database statistics](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/10/05/why-you-should-design-your-database-to-optimise-for-statistics/), and perhaps avoid a human-readable format in favour of a better optimisable one.

Comment: @LukasEder Thank you, I've read your blogpost. IIUIC, you'd recommend something like `months since 2000` or `DATE('2017-03-01')` instead of `'2017-03'` or `201703` so that statistics work better. It's pity that databases have no custom types with `toString` / `fromString`, so we could have both readibility and speed.

Comment: @maaartinus: Yes, that's my recommendation. The `DATE` type (along with a `CHECK` constraint enforcing the day value to be 1) is probably a good compromise in this case. PostgreSQL knows `domain`, a tool to make `CHECK` constraints reusable: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html. Still no `toString()` / `fromString()` formatting option, but at least it's easier to document... Note, my advice is only important if you query large amounts of data with this type as predicate. If you just store the value, then this optimisation might be premature.

Comment: @nazar_art Sort of.... I'm rather confused about what's happening: Before, both `Year` and `Month` were stored as a `Serializable`. I wrote a `YearJavaDescriptor extends AbstractTypeDescriptor<Year>` and now *both* are stored as `int`. I don't have time now to investigate further.

Answer (score 8):

Try to create a converter - `AttributeConverter` implementation for this purpose.

I used in the past something like following:

```
@Entity
public class RealEstateAgency {
    @Column(name = "createdAt")
    @Convert(converter = ZonedDateTimeConverter.class)
    private ZonedDateTime creationDate;
}

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class ZonedDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<ZonedDateTime, Date> {
 
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(ZonedDateTime toConvert) {
        return toConvert == null ? null : Date.from(toConvert.toInstant());
    }
 
    public ZonedDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Date toConvert) {
        return toConvert == null ? null : ZonedDateTime.from(toConvert.toInstant());
    }
}
```

Comment: It's important to remember that it has to be `java.sql.Date`. Stuff like `LocalDate` although independently correctly serialized by Hibernate does not seem to work in this case.

Answer (score 4):

If your JPA provider does not persist a type in a sensible manner (in this case because it is a Java8 class, which was added after JPA 2.1 was approved) then you need to define a JPA 2.1 AttributeConverter to convert it to a standard JPA persistable type (in this case something like java.sql.Date).

Comment: It's java 8, but I'm using hibernate-java8 JAR.

Answer (score 2):

### Using JPA AttributeConverter

For `YearMonth`, you can create the following [`YearMonthDateAttributeConverter`](https://vladmihalcea.com/java-yearmonth-jpa-hibernate/) like this:

```
public class YearMonthDateAttributeConverter
        implements AttributeConverter<YearMonth, java.sql.Date> {
 
    @Override
    public java.sql.Date convertToDatabaseColumn(
            YearMonth attribute) {
        return java.sql.Date.valueOf(attribute.atDay(1));
    }
 
    @Override
    public YearMonth convertToEntityAttribute(
            java.sql.Date dbData) {
        return YearMonth
                .from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(dbData.getTime())
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                .toLocalDate());
    }
}
```

And, use `@Convert` on the `YearMonth` JPA entity property:

```
@Column(name = "published_on", columnDefinition = "date")
@Convert(converter = YearMonthDateAttributeConverter.class)
private YearMonth publishedOn;
```

### Using a Hibernate custom Type

You can create a custom Hibernate Type by extending the `AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType`:

```
public class YearMonthDateType
        extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<YearMonth> {
 
    public static final YearMonthDateType INSTANCE = 
        new YearMonthDateType();
 
    public YearMonthDateType() {
        super(
            DateTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE,
            YearMonthTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE
        );
    }
 
    public String getName() {
        return "yearmonth-date";
    }
 
    @Override
    protected boolean registerUnderJavaType() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And define the [`YearMonthTypeDescriptor`](https://vladmihalcea.com/java-yearmonth-jpa-hibernate/) as follows:

```
public class YearMonthTypeDescriptor
        extends AbstractTypeDescriptor<YearMonth> {
 
    public static final YearMonthTypeDescriptor INSTANCE = 
        new YearMonthTypeDescriptor();
 
    public YearMonthTypeDescriptor() {
        super(YearMonth.class);
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean areEqual(
            YearMonth one, 
            YearMonth another) {
        return Objects.equals(one, another);
    }
 
    @Override
    public String toString(
            YearMonth value) {
        return value.toString();
    }
 
    @Override
    public YearMonth fromString(
            String string) {
        return YearMonth.parse(string);
    }
 
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    @Override
    public <X> X unwrap(
            YearMonth value, 
            Class<X> type, 
            WrapperOptions options) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (String.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            return (X) toString(value);
        }
        if (Date.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            return (X) java.sql.Date.valueOf(value.atDay(1));
        }
        throw unknownUnwrap(type);
    }
 
    @Override
    public <X> YearMonth wrap(
            X value, 
            WrapperOptions options) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (value instanceof String) {
            return fromString((String) value);
        }
        if (value instanceof Date) {
            Date date = (Date) value;
            return YearMonth
                .from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime())
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                .toLocalDate());
        }
        throw unknownWrap(value.getClass());
    }
}
```

> You don't need to write this type by yourself, you can use the [Hibernate Types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) and just declare the Maven dependency like this:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
>     <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
>     <version>${hibernate-types.version}</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

That's it!