# Error deserialize JSON value into type: class java.time.YearMonth

Tags: hibernate, jpa, quarkus, jsonb

Jakarta EE

```
@Entity(name = "Book")
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    private String isbn;

    private String title;

    @Column(name = "published_on", columnDefinition = "date")
    @Convert(converter = YearMonthDateAttributeConverter.class)
    private YearMonth publishedOn;

    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

**I want to insert Year and Month only and I'm using JakartaEE Jsonb. Localdate is working fine but i have to insert the day too. I don't wont to use Jackson.**

[JEE JSON Binding](https://javaee.github.io/jsonb-spec/)

```
public class Book {

    public String isbn;
    public String title;
    public YearMonth publishedOn;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a book instance
        Book book = new Book();
        book.isbn = "123";
        book.title = "Advanced JPA and Hibernate";
        book.publishedOn = YearMonth.of(2022, 9);

        // Create Jsonb and serialize
        Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
        var result = jsonb.toJson(book);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear wtaht the problem is; please add more details about the problems you are facing

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci thanks for your comment, I have updated the question added another example and the link for the JSON Binging spec for more details.
https://javaee.github.io/jsonb-spec/

Comment: I'm still in trouble understanding the real problem, but if your concerns are about using a `date` column in database that's not a big deal: just throw out day from data column (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43059147/how-to-map-java-time-year-and-others-java-time-types-using-hibernate)

Comment: Thanks @LucaBassoRicci my problem is related to JSONB serialization and is very clear if you have an experience in Jakarta EE jsonb spec.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my answer by creating
`YearMonthTypeAdapter` implementing the `JsonAdapter<YearMonth, String>` class, then overrode the below methods:

1. ```
   String adaptToJson(YearMonth date) return date.toString;
   ```
2. ```
   YearMonth adaptFromJson(String string) return YearMonth.parse(string);
   ```